# Testing whether points in two distributions are statistically different

Tags: hypothesis-testing

It's been a long time since I studied stats and what follows is a basic question.

I have summary information on yearly income for both Australia and the UK (see pictures below). I would like to test whether these two distributions are statistically different from one another at the 95th and 99th percentile.

Is there any way to do that from the information contained in these summary plots or is the underlying data required?

[image: Australian Income Distribution]

[image: UK Income Distribution]

Comment: Don't you--at a bare minimum--need to tell us how to convert between dollars and pounds?  And if you're going to do any kind of statistical test, please tell us how these graphs were derived from the underlying data and describe those data.

Comment: How to convert between dollars and pounds? - I intend to use an average Fx rate for 2016.

Comment: I have information on the underlying distribution for the Australian data set but I don't have access to the underlying UK data - hence the question about comparison in this state.

Please tell us how these graphs were derived from the underlying data - The charts depict full-time earnings from those employed in the respective country. In the case of the Australian distribution, the chart was produced after calling the stats::quantile() function in the r programming language.

Comment: "I have information" is quite vague: what information is it?  A sample, a census, a model estimate, something else?  These details are crucial for determining how to perform a statistical comparison.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this whuber. 

The underlying data in both cases result from large scale longitudinal surveys.